# What's the difference between plainToClass and typecasting?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-transformer

Please read this bit first!

The documentation for [typestack-class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) is good for examples, but quite limited in their explanations.

It says here:

```
fetch('users.json').then((users: User[]) => {
  // you can use users here, and type hinting also will be available to you,
  //  but users are not actually instances of User class
  // this means that you can't use methods of User class
});
```

I haven't followed that example, it's just something I read after the fact.
But what I have been doing is this -

Say I had the following JSON:

```
{
  "startTs":"2020-10-16T13:59:52.224Z",
  "endTs":"2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z",
  "frequency":3.505,
  "entrances":0
}
```

And the following class:

```
export class ExxRecord {
    startTs: string;
    endTs: string;
    frequency: number;
    entrances: number;

    constructor(startTs: string, endTs: string, frequency: number, entrances: number) {
        this.startTs = startTs;
        this.endTs = endTs;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.entrances = entrances;
    }

    getEndTs(): string {
        return this.endTs;
    }
}
```

I am able to do the following:

```
import exxData from '../../testData/dataExx.json';

const data = exxData as ExxRecord;
const endTs = data.getEndTs();
```

Why wasn't this used as an example in the docs? I'm able to access the class's method just fine.

Why would I care to use plainToClass to replicate the same (I assume) result? Am I missing something here, would plainToClass give me a different result?

Apologies for any ignorance on my part, I just didn't understand why plainToClass was seemingly "required" for such a task.

Thanks so much :)

EDIT:

My IDE may have been somewhat misleading me:

[image]

But when I try to actually execute that code:

[image]

Comment: You do not have `getEndTs` in your json

Comment: Hi, getEndTs is a class function. It isn't supposed to be a part of any JSON.

Comment: and that is why you convert plain to class.

Comment: But, as I've just explained, I've been able to access the function WITHOUT using plainToClass

Comment: not possible, in that case `exxData` must containe the method. and the json above is missing the method

Comment: I've added two pictures to the end of the original post, does this line up with what you're saying?

Comment: yes, casting will Identify the object as the type but is it really the type ? as you saw that it is not.

Comment: I have noticed this same problem when I have used plainToClass however. Like if for instance I changed the JSON to be:

{
  "startTs":"2020-10-16T13:59:52.224Z",
  "endTs":"2020-10-16T14:00:52.224Z",
  "frequency": "3.505",    < -- a string now, not a number
  "entrances":0
}

And converted it via plainToClass, and then console.log the converted item, it would erroneously say "frequency": "3.505"

So it still feels like it's identified as an object but isn't really

Comment: @cien TS types are just pretend, at runtime they are all gone and you are stuck with the values that the variables actually contain. Spend some time on the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and pay attention to the right side, the compiled code, because that's what your browser will run.

Answer (score 0):

The type casting gets compiled away. This is why the method is not being available at runtime. I've added some comments to make it easier to understand.

This is your source file

```js
// source.ts
import exxData from '../../testData/dataExx.json';

const data = exxData as ExxRecord;
const endTs = data.getEndTs();
```

after you or your bundler runs `tsc`(typescript compiler) you get plain javascript that will look similar to this

```js
// out.js
var exxData = require('../../testData/dataExx.json')

// note no type casting here as types do not affect runtime(enums are exceptions)
const data = exxData;
const endTs = data.getEndTs(); // runtime error
```